# Solving partial differential equation for Laplace equation with $u(x,0) = \sin(\pi x), u(x,1) = 0, u(0, y) = 0, u(1,y) = 0. $

Tags: calculus, partial-differential-equations, boundary-value-problem

I try to solve the following partial differential equation for the Laplace equation on the unit square (i.e. $0 \leq x,y \leq 1$) with boundary conditions
$$
u(x,0) = \sin(\pi x),\\
u(x,1) = 0,\\
u(0, y) = 0,\\
u(1,y) = 0,
$$
so only the bottom boundary is non-zero. This problem comes from "Introduction to Partial Differential Equations" and I am using the method on page 157 from this book.

---

I argue that since both boundaries in the $x$-direction (i.e. the left and right boundary) are zero, it is convenient to examine those first.

The Laplace equations state $u_{t} = u_{xx} + u_{yy} = 0.$ We use separation of variables with the ansatz that $u(x,y) = v(x)w(y)$ to find
$$ 
v''(x) - \lambda v(x) = 0 ,\\
w''(y) + \lambda w(y) = 0, 
$$
where $\lambda$ is the separation constant.

---

Since $v(0) = v(1) = 0$ we know $\lambda < 0$ and then if we let $\lambda = - \omega^{2}$, we know
$$
v(x) = c_{1} \cos(\omega x) + c_{2} \sin(\omega x).
$$
And since we know $v(0)=v(1)=0$ we know only the sine term qualifies and hence we can deduce, using $v(1) = 0$ that
$$
\sin(\omega x) = \sin( \omega ) = 0 \quad  \Rightarrow  \quad \omega = n \pi, \quad n=1,2,3,\dots,
$$
then $\lambda_{n} = -\omega_{n}^{2} = - n^{2} \pi^{2}$.

So we conclude $v_{n}(x) = \sin( n \pi x)$.

---

Now we look at the $y$-direction (i.e. bottom and top boundaries). Since $\lambda <0$ we know
$$
w(y) = c_{1} e^{-\omega y} + c_{2} e^{\omega y}.
$$
We examine the right border and hence set $w(1) = 0 $ which gives
$$
w_{n}(y) = \sinh( \omega( 1-y)) = \sinh ( n \pi (1-y)).
$$

---

We now know that
$$
u_{n} (x,y) = \sin(n \pi x) \sinh(n \pi (1-y)),
$$
and thus we find
$$ 
u(x,y) = \sum_{n=1}^{\infty} c_{n} \sin(n \pi x) \sinh(n \pi (1-y))
$$
and we can use this to derive $c_{n}$ since we know that the bottom boundary gives $u(x,0) = \sin(\pi x)$.  So
$$ 
u(x,0) = \sum_{n=1}^{\infty} c_{n} \sin(n \pi x) \sinh(n \pi) = \sin(\pi x),
$$
**but I do not know how to proceed.**

I reckon we should use Fourier Series but I do not see how.

Comment: What don't you understand about the solution $w_{n}(y)$? To proceed in the second part, just identify terms in the summation with the term on the right i.e \begin{align} \tilde{c}_{1} \sin(\pi x) + \tilde{c}_{2} \sin(2 \pi x) + \tilde{c}_{3} \sin(3 \pi x) + \dots &= u(x, 0) \\ &= \sin(\pi x) \\ &= \sin(\pi x) + \color{red}{0} \sin(2 \pi x) + \color{red}{0} \sin(3 \pi x) + \dots \end{align} where $\tilde{c}_{n} = c_{n} \sinh(n \pi)$. Hence, $c_{1} = 1/\sinh(\pi), c_{n} = 0$ for $n \ne 1$. The solution is then $$u(x,y) = \frac{\sin(\pi x) \sinh(\pi(1-y))}{\sinh(\pi)}$$

Comment: I did not see how we got to $\sinh$, but I do now. Your introduction of $\tilde{c}$ makes it instantly clear.